# Advice on packaging and sending photo prints

Tags: selling

I have a photo lab in the UK who supplies me with my photo prints (16 x 12). At the minute I am selling my prints as framed items but I would like to move into selling the prints without the frame.

My question relates to packing and shipping of individual prints. Should I be packing them in a certain way/method or using certain materials to send the print? Obviously I would imagine that I would need some sort of cardboard backed envelope but I am thinking about what else may be needed to prevent the print from being damaged.

Can someone share there experience and or methods with me?

Thanks

**More Detail**

To expand on the question I believe that I need to mount the prints to a board and then place them inside a clear plastic bag. Is this correct?

Comment: What sort of volume are you (looking into) posting at once?

Comment: Hi, probably individual prints.

Comment: Interestingly, I did the opposite move after reading [Marketing Fine-Art Photography](http://blog.neocamera.com/marketing-fine-art-photography-non-review) which says that the perceived value of photos is higher for a framed print since it a more finished product.

Comment: I think it is down to opinion, I think I read somewhere that someone mentioned that individuals prefer to purchase prints without the frame because that means they are free to frame it how they like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd put the prints in a (neatly folded) plastic bag inside the cardboard backed envelope in an attempt to prevent water damage. In my experience, the Royal Mail aren't the most careful when it comes to handling things.